# Is the arguments object supposed to be an iterable in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterable

In ES6, I was trying to use the `arguments` object as an iterable when passed to the `Set` constructor.  It works fine in IE11 and in Chrome 47.  It does not work in Firefox 43 (throws a `TypeError: arguments is not iterable`).  I've looked through the ES6 spec and cannot really find a definition of whether the `arguments` object should be an iterable or not.

Here's an example of what I was trying to do:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var removes = new Set(arguments);
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return !removes.has(item);
  });
}

// remove items 2, 3, 5 from the passed in array
var result = destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5);
log(result);
```

FYI, I know there are various work-arounds for this code such as copying the arguments object into a real array or using rest arguments.  This question is about whether the `arguments` object is supposed to be an `iterable` or not in ES6 that can be used anywhere iterables are expected.

Comment: This is a known FF bug: [The arguments object should support the ES6 @@iterator protocol](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067049)

Comment: @apsillers - And it looks like the code has already been written to fix it (last month) and it is in the process of being reviewed and tested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose it is a bug in FF's implementation.

As per [9.2.12 FunctionDeclarationInstantiation(func, argumentsList)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) section,

> If argumentsObjectNeeded is true, then
>
> a) If strict is true or if simpleParameterList is false, then
>
> ==> i) Let ao be **CreateUnmappedArgumentsObject**(argumentsList).
>
> b) Else,
>
> ==> i) NOTE mapped argument object is only provided for non-strict functions that don’t have a rest parameter, any parameter default value initializers, or any destructured parameters .
>
> ==> ii) Let ao be **CreateMappedArgumentsObject**(func, formals, argumentsList, env).

Both [`CreateMappedArgumentsObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createmappedargumentsobject) and [`CreateUnmappedArgumentsObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createunmappedargumentsobject) have

> Perform **DefinePropertyOrThrow**(obj, **@@iterator**, PropertyDescriptor {[[Value]]:%ArrayProto_values%, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}).

It means that `@@iterator` property should have been actually defined on the `arguments` object.

Comment: And, to demonstrate definitively that it's not defined: `(function(a) { return arguments[Symbol.iterator] })(1)` produces `undefined` in FF, but a function in other browsers.

Comment: With a better idea what to search for now, I searched for a Firefox bug report on this and found it here: [The arguments object should support the ES6 @@iterator protocol](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067049).  It looks like it is in the process of being released (code written to fix the bug last month).

Comment: Thx for the pointer to the right place in the ES6 spec.  I was expecting the description of the `arguments` object to mention `@@iterator`, but it was not mentioned there at all.  The spec itself appears to be more procedural than object oriented which seems slightly ironic.

Comment: The bug fix is now released and it works in Firefox 46.